# Binding C-c C-e lo to “print” button

Tags: key-bindings

I use org mode for my routine work. I use sequence C-c C-e lo to export and open pdf almost 30 times a day Is it possible to bind this  sequence to print button. It will make my job easy

Comment: Take a look at `key-translation-map`'s docstring.

Comment: What is this `lo` you have (do you really mean the `C-c C-e l o` sequence, or was the `lo` just a typo)?  And what "print" button are you thinking of?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Vaibhav type `C-h k` and then click on the print button you're referring to, and Emacs should tell you the name of the command.

Comment: @Stefan  as a sequence

Comment: @Stefan I guess that this question is actually about org-mode. There `C-c C-e` is `org-export-dispatch` generating a menu where the keystrokes `l` and `o` stand for `Export to *L*aTeX` and `As PDF and *o*pen`, respectively. That leads me to the assumption that this question is not really about `ps-print-buffer` or anything similar but about org-mode export to LaTeX and PDF. @Vaibhav: If my assumption is right please clarify that in the question.

Comment: In any case, the recommended way to add local or global private keybindings is to bind them to `C-c` followed by an unmodified alphabetic character (possibly followed by more keystrokes). That way, you are guaranteed not to overwrite any default keybindings, as these prefixes are reserved for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
(defun org-export-to-pdf-and-open ()
  (org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<print>") #'org-export-to-pdf-and-open)
```

(Your question is not very clear, let me know if I guessed incorrectly
what you wanted.)